# How to order and separate docs in firebase if timestamp is a pass date or a future date?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a counting app, I want to display negative counters in descending order, but the positive counters in ascending order.

Currently, I only know how to do either of them, but not where should I edit my code to add the if/else to output the different orders.

This is the current rendered output:

[image]

But the goal is that negative counters should be descending, so in this example "Next cup of coffee" should be first, then "Next meal", and on the other side should remain ascending.

This is my current code:

```
db.collection('counters').orderBy("timestamp", "desc").onSnapshot(snapshot => {setInterval(() => 
counters(snapshot.docs), 1000);});
```

This is what renders the counters:

```
function renderCounter(doc){

    const data = doc.data();
    const date = data.timestamp.toDate();
    
    let box = document.createElement('div'); box.classList.add('counter');  
    let header = document.createElement('div'); header.classList.add('keydata'); header.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);    
    let cross = document.createElement('h5'); cross.classList.add('data'); cross.textContent = "x";

    let timestamp = document.createElement('h5'); timestamp.textContent = dateFormat(date);
    let sign = ''; if (date - new Date > 0) {sign = "-"} else if (date - new Date < 0) {sign = "+"};
    let activeCount = document.createElement('h4'); activeCount.textContent = "T" + sign + " " + countThis(date);
    let title = document.createElement('p'); title.classList.add('micro'); title.textContent = data.title;  

    box.appendChild(header);
    header.appendChild(timestamp);
    header.appendChild(cross);
    box.appendChild(activeCount);
    box.appendChild(title);

    if (date - new Date > 0 ) {     
        counterModuleN.appendChild(box);
    }

    else if (date - new Date < 0) {
        counterModuleP.appendChild(box);
    }
    
    cross.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        let id = e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');
        db.collection('counters').doc(id).delete();
    });
}
```

Is there a way to sort conditional data by different orders?

Comment: Hey! I wasn't able to try it since adding some other functionality rendered some bugs on my code. I'll try it later, and hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

To construct a dynamic query like that, it helps to realize that each time you call `where` or `orderBy` or similar, you get back a new query object.

So something like this should work:

```
var query = db.collection('counters');
var now = Date.now();
if(date - now > 0){
  query = query.orderBy("timestamp");
}
else if(date - now < 0){
  query = query.orderBy("timestamp", "desc");
}
query.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
  counters(snapshot.docs);
});
```

---

If you want, you can shorten the conditional a bit to:

```
query = query.orderBy("timestamp", (date - now) > 0 ? "asc" : "desc");
```

Comment: Well Frank, it does sort the content but it makes no distinction of positive and negative counters, it simple sorts them all as one

Comment: Hey Frank, added more information to clear this problem up, just in case.

Comment: You posted a problem with retrieving ordered data from the database, which I tried to help with. But it it's about updating the UI, if I understand correctly. It sounds like you've moved on from the original problem, which means you should really open a new question. Which I just see you've already done, so I'm not sure what's left to do for this question.